# Monitor Twilio error logs using Dynatrace

Tags: twilio, dynatrace

I have tried to find a solution for it but with no luck.

Maybe someone can please help me to understand if and how I can monitor Twilio errors log using Dynatrace?

I mean, pushing Twilio error logs to Dynatrace platform and monitor it from there.

I know about a way to push alerts notification from Twilio to a specific webhook URL but I got stuck there.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. You understand what you need to do on the Twilio side, when there's an error Twilio will trigger a webhook. I don't know about Dynatrace myself, it looks like a complicated system that relies on an integrated agent. I would contact Dynatrace support to see if they have suggestions for how to ingest external events like this.

Comment: Alright. Thank you!